# What does "too many positional options" mean when doing a mongoexport?

Tags: mongodb

`mongoexport -h db.mysite.com -u myUser -p myPass -c myCollection`

But the response I get is:

`ERROR: too many positional options`

What's that about?

Comment: What is the `<http://db.mysite.com>` doing in there?

Comment: I have a same problem > mongoexport --host Remote --port 27017 --collection Event  --db mana --fields userName --query {"_class" : "blaablaEvent","rewardStatus" : "NEW"} --out out.csv

Comment: In general it is parsing error (some extra space or something like that), once try to "type" the command again instead of copying it from somewhere.

Comment: The reason behind this might be exporting in CSV format. Try exporting in json.

Answer (score 42):

I had this same problem. In my case, I was using `mongoexport` with the `--query` option, which expects a JSON document, such as:

```
mongoexport ... --query {field: 'value'} ...
```

I needed to surround the document with quotes:

```
mongoexport ... --query "{field: 'value'}" ...
```

Comment: Some OS's work slightly differently. The above solution worked for me on Windows, but for a colleague (Mac)  he had to put the single quotes (') on the outside and double quotes (") on the inside.
Win: mongoexport ... --query "{field: 'value'}" ...
Mac: mongoexport ... --query '{field: "value"}' ...

Comment: In linux not found already the correct match using subprocess it's not working if I copy paste the command it works!

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. Found a group post somewhere which said to remove the space between the '-p' and the password, which worked for me.

Your sample command should be:

```
mongoexport -h db.mysite.com -u myUser -pmyPass -c myCollection
```

Comment: Additionally, watch out for spaces with the -f option.  Your fields shouldn't be space out between commas

Comment: Super weird. The same version of mongodump (2.6.11) on macOS vs Ubuntu, macOS version works with a space, the Ubuntu version does not.

Answer (score 11):

The same error I have encountered while importing a csv file.
But its just, the fact that the field list which you pass for that csv file import may have blank spaces.
Just clear the blank spaces in field list.

Its the parsing error.

Comment: Yes, that's it.... posted the export into sublime, cleaned up, it worked for me.  Thanks -

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with `mongodump`. After searching a bit, I found out that using the `--out` parameter to specify the output directory would solve this issue. The syntax for using the out parameter is

```
mongoexport --collection collection --out collection.json
```

Also in case your Mongodb instance isn't running, then you could use the --dbpath to specify the exact path to the files of your instance.

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with the mongoexport utility (using 2.0.2).  My fix was to use the FULL parameter name (i.e. not -d, instead use --db).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes editor will screw it up (such as evernote). I fixed the issue by retyping the command in terminal.

Comment: Evernote changed the '--query' to a '—query' and that screwed the pooch for me

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck in same situation and found what was causing it.

1. Make sure you are exporting in CSV format by adding parameter `--type csv`
2. Make sure there are no spaces in fields name, 
   Example: `--fields _id,  desc` is wrong but `--fields id,desc,price` is good

Answer (score 2):

This also works if you place the -c option first. For me, this order does work:

```
mongoexport -c collection -h ds111111.mlab.com:11111 -u user -p pass -d mydb
```

You can also leave the pass out and the server will ask you to enter the pass. This only works if the server supports SASL authentication (mlab does not for example).

Answer (score 2):

for the (Error: Too many arguments)

Dont Use Space Between the Fields

try:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db local --collection epfo_input --type=csv --out epfo_input.csv --fields cin,name,search_string,EstablishmentID,EstablishmentName,Address,officeName
```

Dont_Try:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db local --collection epfo_input --type=csv --out epfo_input.csv --fields cin,name,search_string,Establishment ID,Establishment Name,Address,office Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with starting mongod. I used the following command:

> ./mongod --port 27001 --replSet abc -- dbpath /Users/seanfoley/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.3/bin/1 --logpath /Users/seanfoley/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.3/log.1 --logappend --oplogSize 5 --smallfiles --fork

The following error message appeared:

> Error parsing command line: too many positional options have been specified on the command line

What fixed this issue was removing the single space between the '--' and 'dbpath'

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue

```
$too many positional arguments
$try 'mongorestore --help' for more information
```

Simply fix for me was to wrap the path location in quotes **" "**

**This Failed:**

```
mongorestore -h MY.mlab.com:MYPORT -d MYDBNAME -u ADMIN -p PASSWORD C:\Here\There\And\Back\Again
```

**This Worked:**

```
mongorestore -h MY.mlab.com:MYPORT -d MYDBNAME -u ADMIN -p PASSWORD "C:\Here\There\And\Back\Again"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using the "mongod --dbpath" command. What I was doing looked somewhat like this:

`mongod --dbpath c:/Users/HP/Desktop/Mongo_Data`

where as the command syntax was supposed to be:

```
mongod --dbpath=c:/Users/HP/Desktop/Mongo_Data
```

This worked for me. Apart from this one may take a note of the command function and syntaxes using the `mongod --help` command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to write the port separately from the server connection. This worked for me:

> mongoexport --host=HOST --port=PORT --db=DB --collection=COLLECTION 
>   --out=OUTPUT.json -u USER -p PASS

Answer (score -3):

Create a json file in the same folder where you have your `mongod.exe`.

eg: coll.json

and open a command prompt in this folder.

type this below in CMD.

> mongoexport --db databasename --collection collectionname --out
>   coll.json

and you will see like a progress bar very cool exporting all data.