# How can I get all the fieldnames of a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

My requirement is to print all the data from a collection to a CSV file, but I don't know the name of all the fields.

When I am using the following format, I get the error

mongoexport -h *ServerName* -p *PortName* -c *CollectionName* -csv "C:\data.csv" -u *UserId* -p *Password*

```
ERROR: too many positional options
```

To use CSV, one need to specify --fields or --fieldFile...for which I need to know the name of all possible fields in a given collection.

Anybody knows how to get all the fieldnames of a collection ? Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "too many positional options" mean when doing a mongoexport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521163/what-does-too-many-positional-options-mean-when-doing-a-mongoexport)

Comment: It's actually an oddity of the command line tool if you look at the linked duplicate question's answer.

Comment: No I don't think its the misbehavior of the tool. Basically it boils down to questions...How to pull all the distinct columns from a collection ?

Comment: You're getting the error likely because you have a space between the `-p` and the `password`.

Comment: Doesnot help removing the space. Also I corrected -p for port. mongoexport -h ServerName -port PortName -c CollectionName -csv "C:\data.csv" -u UserId -p Password

Comment: I am rephrasing my question below :- How to pull all the distinct columns from a collection ?

Comment: You still show a space in the command line around password. There are already answers to both questions you've got on StackOverflow and other web sites.

Comment: First of all...space in Passpord have no effect. I have already verified that. If you do mongoexport -h you can see that too. Second, none of the other posts answer my question "How to pull all the distinct columns from a collection"; especially when my documents have n depths.

Comment: Try this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection

Comment: specify DB name (-db DB_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map-reduce or a schema analyzer tool like [`variety`](https://github.com/variety/variety) to determine the set of columns in a collection.

A map-reduce giving you a frequency count of each field name in the collection:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() { for (var key in this) { emit(key, 1); } },
    function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values); },
    {out: {inline: 1}}
)
```