# MongoDB CSV Export

Tags: mongodb

I'm having an issue with mongoDB doing a CSV export and I just need a new set of eyes to see what's wrong.

```
mongoexport —-database twitter_database —-collection tweets --csv --fields geo,lang --out m_twitter.csv
```

I'm getting a ERROR: too many positional options

I'm not sure why. I must be missing something.

Comment: Try to pass fields in quotes : `... --fields "geo,lang" ...`

Comment: Here is a similar question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521163/what-does-too-many-positional-options-mean-when-doing-a-mongoexport

Comment: @u_mulder yeah that didn't work either.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 looked at that and tried those. It's really weird.

Comment: Which OS are you on?  Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 OS X 10.9

Comment: This answer helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521163/what-does-too-many-positional-options-mean-when-doing-a-mongoexport/52459340#52459340