# mongoexport regex unnknown option

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoexport

```
mongoexport --db ucc_prod /host:myserver /port:27017 --username user1 --password password1 /query:'{copysheet: {$regex: "/^.*pdf/"}}' /out:copysheets.csv --type=csv --fields svOrderId,svItemId --collection copies
```

gives me error

```
2016-09-02T08:17:34.632-0500    error parsing command line options: unknown option "^.*pdf/}}'"
```

What syntax am I missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$regex: /^.*pdf/`?

Comment: Try `'{ "copysheet": { "$regex": "^.*pdf", "$options": "" }}'`

Comment: I get the following error now: 2016-09-02T08:59:46.604-0500    too many positional arguments: [copysheet: { $regex: ^.*pdf, $options:  }}']

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13292572/3832970. Well, maybe you need to swap the quotation marks? `--query "{ 'copysheet': { '$regex': '^.*pdf', '$options':'' }}"` (especially if you are on Windows).

Comment: Aha, Swapping the quotation marks did the trick :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
--query "{ 'copysheet': { '$regex': '^.*pdf', '$options':'' }}"
```

The point is that you should pass the data to the `query` argument as JSON.

See [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query):

> `--query <JSON>, -q <JSON>`
>   Provides a [JSON document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-json-document) as a query that optionally limits the documents returned in the export. Specify JSON in [strict format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

**Note**: on different systems, you might need to swap single with double quotes.

Comment: This answer is great! Just a bit more hint:
In my case, mongoexport in Windows CMD forced me to wrap the query string with double quotes, then the remote Mongo server required me to wrap field names and strings with double quotes too. Eventually I had to escape the double quotes in the query in order for it to work. E.g., `--query "{\"fieldName\": {\"$regex\": \"search-string\", \"$options\": \"i\"}}"`.